# "Do something" vs. "get somehing done"

Tags: difference

Is there any difference in meaning between *do something* and *get something done*? For example:

> I am sorry, but I can't go out with you today. I need to **do** my homework.
>
> I am sorry, but I can't go out with you today. I need to **get** my
> homework **done**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Get something done* can mean 'employ someone to do it for you' - *I need to get my hair cut*. Obviously it doesn't mean that in this case, but it implies that the task is one that needs to be dealt with before you can move on.